# Is there way to return the name of a function to a string in Rust?

Tags: rust

So my question is whether this is possible, and if it is, how would one implement this.
For example,

```
fn some_fn(){}
let name = get_name_of(some_fn);
println!({}, name);
```

Which outputs

```
some_fn
```

Would an implementation like this be possible?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1743 There were attempts to implement it but not completed https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/49820

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this currently does not seem to be possible as of `1.44`.

Depending on your use case, you could of course still manually specify the name using macros such as [`println!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.println.html) or format the given function using [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html).

For example, the following will print `fn: some_fn`:

```
fn main() {
    println!("fn: {}", std::stringify!(some_fn));
}

fn some_fn() {}
```

The downside is that it simply prints the given argument and does not allow you to get the actual function name. Here's an example where it fails, as `fn: f` and not `fn: some_fn` will be returned:

```rust
fn main() {
    some_fn_as_param(&some_fn);
}

fn some_fn() {}

fn some_fn_as_param(f: &dyn Fn()) {
    println!("fn: {}", stringify!(f));
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, talk of such a `macro` for `rust` can be tracked here:

- [rust-lang/rfcs (issue), "Macro that expands into string holding function name (or module path, etc)"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1743)
- [rust-lang/rfcs (pr), "A macro to get the current function name."](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2818)